# Etymology of the term "stabilised" for Heegaard splittings

Tags: terminology, math-history, low-dimensional-topology

A Heegaard splitting of a 3-manifold $ M = H \cup H' $ is *stabilised* if there exist essential discs in $ H $ and $ H' $ whose boundary curves intersect transversely at a single point. Equivalently, a genus $ g $ Heegaard splitting is *stabilised* if it is obtained from a lower genus Heegaard splitting by adding an unknotted handle to each handlebody (more formally, see the bottom of page 1 of [this paper](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Emgscharl/papers/comparing04.pdf)).

Usually when I see the word 'stable' in mathematics, it refers to a process which terminates: that is, one takes an object, performs some 'stablisation' procedure a certain number of times until the procedure becomes stationary, and then stops: so a stable object is one which is equal (or isomorphic or isotopic or whatever) to its stablisation, or something similar. Clearly this is not the case here, since you can stablise any Heegaard splitting and get one of higher genus, even one which is already stable.

**Question(s)**. What is the etymology of the term "stabilised" in reference to Heegard splittings? Is there a historical reference (e.g. the first author to use this term) which gives some justification for this choice of word?

My guess is that it has something to do with the [stabilisation conjecture](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/geometry-and-topology/volume-13/issue-4/Stabilization-of-Heegaard-splittings/10.2140/gt.2009.13.2029.pdf), which was that a single stabilisation always sufficed to turn non-equivalent Heegaard splittings into equivalent ones: if a Heegaard splitting was stable, according to the conjecture, it was unique (so the 'terminating procedure' here is going up the chain of Heegaard splittings until you reach the first one where everything is unique, and then uniqueness as a property is preserved if you keep going). Therefore, an answer to my question could be a citation which proves that this is the historic reason why the term was chosen---even implicitly: if the first known use of the word "stabilisation" for certain Heegaard splittings is in conjunction with this conjecture or related theorems then that is an answer.

Comment: In your reading of that paper of Rubinstein and Scharlemann that you linked, did you notice the last sentence of the abstract? And did you get as far as Theorem 11.5 and Corollary 11.6 on page 4 in which that sentence is stated formally? I think those results might answer your questions.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, this is the meaning of the word which I put forward in the question as a possible explanation (in the final paragraph, I phrased it in terms of the conjecture but of course a weaker result is true). However this paper does not answer the question: how do I know that the original meaning of stabilisation is stabilisation of some other topological invariant (some related homology group or something) and that this other meaning is a happy accident? This is why I am asking for an explicit historical citation where someone says "we call these manifolds 'stabilised' because...".

Comment: Of course my previous comment should read "how do I know that the original meaning of stabilisation is **not** stabilisation of some other topological invariant"

Comment: I think all that's going on here is something that happens quite commonly in mathematics. Namely, a word --- such as *stabilization* --- which has a particular meaning in one particular mathematical context (e.g. homology stabilization) is being repurposed to have a different meaning in a different mathematical context.

Comment: It's not so much an issue of "happy accident". It's more an issue of an author, under pressure to write their ideas down, says to themself: "Hmmm, my concept is sort-kinda similar to stabilization in the homology context... I think I'll borrow that word." In this case, the similarity is quite vague: as a certain index increases (e.g. rank of a Lie group; rank of a Heegard decomposition), a certain mathematical measurement is staying the same. But that vagueness doesn't stop the author from repurposing the word.

Comment: Anyway, I'm only trying to give you an idea of how these terminology "accidents" arise in real-life mathematical writing.

Comment: Yes exactly. But who first wrote down the term? It doesn't appear in the work of Singer, for instance (so far as I can see, maybe I missed it). I'm not disputing that this is probably the correct meaning (in fact this is the meaning which I guessed, in the question). I am asking for its etymology (even less, just who first used it and where). If it was first used in this context of equivalent Heegaard splittings, then this answers my question.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase the question to make it clear that I'm looking for historical references.

Comment: Well, there's the [Freudenthal Suspension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_suspension_theorem) from 1937, long predating Rubinstein and Scharlemann.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will have to think for a bit, I can't immediately see the connection between suspensions and the origin of the stabilisation conjecture. So far as I can see Singer was the first person to study stabilisation (and prove that in an orientable 3-manifold all splittings can be made equivalent by iterating stabilisation) in a 1933 paper, but he does not use this term....

Comment: ...Therefore I can conclude the term was introduced by some author after this paper and since all such authors use this term only in conjunction with the stabilisation conjecture etc., I can conclude that was introduced specifically in order to study this set of theorems (so there is not some more general meaning of stability which this was chosen to coincide). I will write up an answer with the full history of the term when I am back in my office. Thanks for your discussion!

Comment: You might keep in mind: the general concept of stabilization is that a sequence of invariants constructed in a certain manner eventually becomes constant. Your stabilization conjecture for Heegard splittings is like that. The Freundenthal Suspension Theorem has, as a corollary (explained in that link) that $\pi_{n+k}(S^k)$ is eventually constant (holding $n$ fixed and letting $k$ index the sequence). There are also homology stabilization theorems in Lie group land. If you want to find the deepest historical examples of this phenomenon, you'll have to step outside of Heegard splittings.

Comment: Yes, but I am only interested in the etymology of the word as it relates to Heegard splittings, not topology (or mathematics) in general. Anyway thanks for the links